# helm install nuclio on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nuclio

I'm trying to install nuclio on k8s cluster but still have this error:

```
**rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: CustomResourceDefinition "nuclioapigateways.nuclio.io" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "spark": current value is "argocd"**
```

Any help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the helm install command?

Answer (score 0):

You can't install the same thing from two different Helm apps. You have previously installed this chart and didn't fully clean it up (or it's just actually in use by someone else). You can manually delete the CRD via `kubectl delete crd` but of course you should be *very* certain it's safe to do that first.